# Select DISTINCT en codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter-3

Hola me podrían ayudar a hacer esta consulta con codeigniter y acceder al resultado que arroje:

```
  $consulta = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT documentos.titulo_principal, documentos.descripcion, autores.nombre, areas.nombre
                                    FROM documentos  
                                    INNER JOIN documento_area ON documentos.id_documento = documento_area.id_documento
                                    INNER JOIN areas ON areas.id_area = documento_area.id_area
                                    INNER JOIN documento_autor ON documentos.id_documento = documento_autor.id_documento
                                    INNER JOIN autores ON autores.id_autor = documento_autor.id_autor
                                    INNER JOIN documento_palabra ON  documentos.id_documento = documento_palabra.id_documento
                                    INNER JOIN palabraclave ON palabraclave.id_palabra = documento_palabra.id_palabra
                                    WHERE palabraclave.nombre LIKE '%$palabra%' OR areas.nombre LIKE '%$palabra%' OR autores.nombre LIKE '%$palabra%'
                                    OR autores.apellido LIKE '%$palabra%' OR autores.acronimo LIKE '%$palabra%'");
```

Les agradezco mucho. Vi algo en el stackoverflow.com pero solo menciona el select distinc no el inner join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con este código.

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('documentos.titulo_principal,documentos.descripcion,autores.nombre,areas.nombre');
$this->db->from('documentos');
$this->db->join('documento_area', 'documentos.id_documento = documento_area.id_documento');
$this->db->join('areas', 'areas.id_area = documento_area.id_area');
$this->db->join('documento_autor', 'documentos.id_documento = documento_autor.id_documento');
$this->db->join('autores', 'autores.id_autor = documento_autor.id_autor');
$this->db->join('documento_palabra', 'documentos.id_documento = documento_palabra.id_documento');
$this->db->join('palabraclave', 'palabraclave.id_palabra = documento_palabra.id_palabra');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias si hace la consulta sin error, ahora como lo mencione debo acceder a ese resultado. según lo visto en el resultado de la consulta:

Comment: CI_DB_mysqli_result Object ( [conn_id] => mysqli Object ( [affected_rows] => 1 [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 76b08b24596e12d4553bd41fc93cccd5bac2fe7a $ [client_version] => 50011 [connect_errno] => 0 [connect_error] => [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [field_count] => 4 [host_info] => localhost via TCP/IP [info] => [insert_id] => 0 [server_info] => 5.5.5-10.1.16-MariaDB [server_version] => 50505 [stat] => Uptime: 5595 Threads: 1 Questions: 1495 Slow queries: 0 Opens:

Comment: 48 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 41 Queries per second avg: 0.267 [sqlstate] => 00000 [protocol_version] => 10 [thread_id] => 109 [warning_count] => 0 ) [result_id] => mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 4 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 ) [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => [row_data] => )

Comment: Le agradecería si me indicara como podría hacerlo.